# How to Vectorize splitting a Date in R into Multiple Columns

Tags: r, vectorization

I have a dataset which looks like:

```
mother_id,dateOfBirth
1,1962-09-24
2,1991-02-19
3,1978-11-11
```

I need to extract the constituent elements (day,month,year) from date of birth and put them in corresponding columns to look like:

```
mother_id,dateOfBirth,dayOfBirth,monthOfBirth,yearOfBirth
1,1962-09-24,24,09,1962
2,1991-02-19,19,02,1991
3,1978-11-11,11,11,1978
```

Currently, I have it coded as a loop:

```
data <- read.csv("/home/tumaini/Desktop/IHI-Projects/Data-Linkage/matching file dss nacp.csv",stringsAsFactors = F)
dss_individuals <- read.csv("/home/tumaini/Desktop/IHI-Projects/Data-Linkage/Data/dssIndividuals.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)

lookup <- data[,c("patientid","extId")]

# remove duplicates
lookup <- lookup[!(duplicated(lookup$patientid)),]

dss_individuals$dateOfBirth <- as.character.Date(dss_individuals$dob)


dss_individuals$dayOfBirth <- 0
dss_individuals$monthOfBirth <- 0
dss_individuals$yearOfBirth <- 0

# Loop starts here    
for(i in 1:nrow(dss_individuals)){ #nrow(dss_individuals)
    split_list <- unlist(strsplit(dss_individuals[i,]$dateOfBirth,'[- ]'))

    dss_individuals[i,]["dayOfBirth"] <- split_list[3]
    dss_individuals[i,]["monthOfBirth"] <- split_list[2]
    dss_individuals[i,]["yearOfBirth"] <- split_list[1]
}
```

This seems to work, but is horrendously slow as I have 400 000 rows. Is there a way I can get this done more efficiently?

Comment: Check out lubridate package, that extract year, month and things directly from the date.

Comment: Numerous ways to do it. I like `splitstackshape::cSplit(dss_individuals, "dateOfBirth", "-", drop = F)`.

Comment: @abhiieor I have tried your solution but it seems to give a uniform value for each observation of dayOfBirth, etc, ie no correlation between dateOfBirth and the resulting dayOfBirth

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli let me have a look at the lubridate package now, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this will solve your speed issues but here is a nicer way of doing it using dplyr and lubridate. In general when it comes to manipulating data.frames I personally recommend using either data.tables or dplyr. Data.tables is supposed to be faster but dplyr is more verbose which I personally prefer as I find it easier to pick up my code after not having read it for months.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

dat <- data.frame( mother_id = c(1,2,3),
                   dateOfBirth = ymd(c( "1962-09-24" ,"1991-02-19" ,"1978-11-11"))
)


dat %>%  mutate( year  = year(dateOfBirth) , 
                 month = month(dateOfBirth),
                 day   = day(dateOfBirth)  )
```

Or you can use the mutate_each function to save having to write the variable name multiple times (though you get less control over the name of the output variables)

```
dat %>% mutate_each( funs(year , month , day) , dateOfBirth)
```

Comment: As shown [by a poster below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38185203/4651564) lubridate is in fact faster than many of the other solutions suggested so far :)

Comment: `lubridate` uses POSIXlt objects behind the scenes. These use 5x more memory than Date objects, and so potentially this could be slower when you have a lot of data.

Answer (score 3):

I compared the speed of `substr`, `format`, and use of `lubridate`. It seems that `lubridate` and `format` are much faster than `substr`, if the the variable is stored as date. However, substr would be fastest if the variable is stored as character vector. The results of a single run is shown.

```
x <- sample(
    seq(as.Date('1000/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"),
    400000, replace = T)

system.time({
    y <- substr(x, 1, 4)
    m <- substr(x, 6, 7)
    d <- substr(x, 9, 10)
})
# user  system elapsed 
# 3.775   0.004   3.779 

system.time({
    y <- format(x,"%y")
    m <- format(x,"%m")
    d <- format(x,"%d")
})
# user  system elapsed 
# 1.118   0.000   1.118 

system.time({
    y <- year(x)
    m <- month(x)
    d <- day(x)
})
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.951   0.000   0.951 

x1 <- as.character(x)
system.time({
    y <- substr(x1, 1, 4)
    m <- substr(x1, 6, 7)
    d <- substr(x1, 9, 10)
})
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.082   0.000   0.082
```

Comment: You can simplify how you time an operation by wrapping it inside the system.time for example
`system.time({
ys.time()
y <- substr(x, 1, 4)
m <- substr(x, 6, 7)
d <- substr(x, 9, 10)
})
`

Comment: Thanks. I edited the code following suggestion. ;). @C_G

Comment: Can you include the results in your post?

Comment: Sure. I added results for a single run. @James

Comment: @user53777 Thanks. Interesting results. You should probably put the `as.character` call into the timing too to be a fair comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some solutions.  These solutions each (i) use 1 or 2 lines of code and (ii) return *numeric* year, month and day columns.   In addition, the first two solutions use no packages -- the third uses chron's `month.day.year` function.

**1) POSIXlt** Convert to `"POSIXlt"` class and pick off the parts.

```
lt <- as.POSIXlt(DF$dateOfBirth, origin = "1970-01-01")
transform(DF, year = lt$year + 1900, month = lt$mon + 1, day = lt$mday)
```

giving:

```
  mother_id dateOfBirth year month day
1         1  1962-09-24 1962     9  24
2         2  1991-02-19 1991     2  19
3         3  1978-11-11 1978    11  11
```

**2) read.table**

```
cbind(DF, read.table(text = format(DF$dateOfBirth), sep = "-", 
  col.names = c("year", "month", "day")))
```

giving:

```
  mother_id dateOfBirth year month day
1         1  1962-09-24 1962     9  24
2         2  1991-02-19 1991     2  19
3         3  1978-11-11 1978    11  11
```

**3) chron::month.day.year**

```
library(chron)
cbind(DF, month.day.year(DF$dateOfBirth))
```

giving:

```
  mother_id dateOfBirth month day year
1         1  1962-09-24     9  24 1962
2         2  1991-02-19     2  19 1991
3         3  1978-11-11    11  11 1978
```

**Note 1:** Often when year, month and day are added to data it is not really necessary and in fact they could be generated on the fly when needed using `format`, `substr` or `as.POSIXlt` so you might critically examine whether you actually need to do this.

**Note 2:** The input data frame, `DF` in reproducible form, was assumed to be:

```
Lines <- "mother_id,dateOfBirth
1,1962-09-24
2,1991-02-19
3,1978-11-11"

DF <- read.csv(text = Lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `format` once for each part:

```
dss_individuals$dayOfBirth <- format(dss_individuals$dateOfBirth,"%d")
dss_individuals$monthOfBirth <- format(dss_individuals$dateOfBirth,"%m")
dss_individuals$yearOfBirth <- format(dss_individuals$dateOfBirth,"%Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `substr` function from the base package (or other functions from the nice `stringr` package) to extract different parts of a string. This function may assume that day, month and year are always in the same place and with the same length.

The `strsplit` function is vectorized so using `rbind.data.frame` to convert your list to a dataframe works:

```
do.call(rbind.data.frame, strsplit(df$dateOfBirth, split = '-'))
```

Results need to be transposed in order to be used: you can do it using `do.call` or the `t` function.